# hadoop get file name in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I have configured the `job` to output multiple files as follows:

```
        // in the run:
        // Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
                LongWritable.class, Text.class);
        // Defines additional sequence-file based output 'sequence' for the job
        MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "seq",
                SequenceFileOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

I also have a multiple outputs setup:

```
    private MultipleOutputs mos;

    public void setup(Context context) {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
    }
```

And i am trying to define each reducer's output file to have the name of the input file whose information it processes:

```
        public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> counts,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable count : counts) {
                sum += count.get();
            }

            String filename = context.getFileClassPaths()[0].toString();
            Text key = new Text(filename);// new Text("");
            mos.write(word, new IntWritable(sum), generateFileName(key, new Text("value")));
        }
```

However, the filename is always null. Can anyone point to a documentation for the latest version of Hadoop or please tell me what am i doing wrong? I have only been able to find answers to this question unsing an outdated API.

I have also tried `context.getInputSplit()` but it gives a compiler error...

Comment: According to the documentation, that method returns "the file entries in the classpath", which would not be the output filename.

Comment: The latest documentation for the method you do want is FileOutputFormat#getOutputName.. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat.html#getOutputName(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext)

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you :D

Comment: Welcome. Sorry can't give an answer since I'm not so sure how to get the OutputFormat from the Context